# css java script adding if else

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `black` and `green` css classes. I need to edit this JavaScript using `if else elseif` to put the `black` and `green` classes.

I just have to use `green`. How to put `black` using `elseif`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       });
   //drop down menu
       $(".drop-down").hover(function() {
         $('.green').addClass('display-on');
       });
       $(".drop-down").mouseleave(function() {
         $('.green').removeClass('display-on');
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough try adding more detail so we can help you further. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let's see your html so we know how it's structured.

Comment: What language can you speak properly? Might be easier to help.

Comment: thinks help  sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".d-d").hover(function(){

  if( $(".green").hasClass("d-on") ){
  
   $(".green").removeClass("d-on");
  
  }else{
  
    $(".green").addClass("d-on");
  
  }
  
});
```

```css
.d-d{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: grey;
}

.green{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: green;
}

.d-on{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-d"></div>
<br>
<div class="green"></div>
```